# table heading splitting

Tags: tables, tabulary

I'm using two-column formate and aiming to make a table that spans only one column, though for small heading it's okay, however, when the length of heading is increasing the table goes to the 2nd column. Can you suggest so that I can divide my heading into two lines? I used \thead for this but it didn't work for me. Thanks in advance

enter code here

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{center}
\label{table_par}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|c|c|c}
&\textbf{\small}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\small Designed Cases}}\\
\cline{3-5}


 \textbf{{\small Tariffs}} &\textbf{ \small}& \textbf{\small Without case and data}& \textbf{\small With case and data}& \textbf{\small With} \\ 



 \hline\hline


\multirow{2}{*}{1}   &abc                     &5.34      &5.27     &4.00     \\ 
                              &Decrease &---        &1.37\%  &28.7\%  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{2}  &abc                    &5.69     &5.62     &3.8        \\ 
                              &Decrease  &---      &1.36\%   &39.42\%   \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could add a hand drawn sketch of the desired table output since it is not clear from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{center}
\label{table_par}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|c|c|c}
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\small Designed Cases}}\\
\cline{3-5}
&\textbf{ \small}& \textbf{\small Without case}& \textbf{\small With case}&  \\
\textbf{{\small Tariffs}} & & \textbf{\small and data}& \textbf{\small and data}& \textbf{\small With} \\
\hline\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1}   &abc                     &5.34      &5.27     &4.00     \\
                           &Decrease &---        &1.37\%  &28.7\%  \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{2}  &abc                    &5.69     &5.62     &3.8        \\
                             &Decrease  &---      &1.36\%   &39.42\%   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: decimals not aligned

Comment: Thanks, New to latex, but can you address the js bibra comment?